# Alternative to PyGObject?

Tags: python, gobject, pygobject

Does anyone have an alternative to using PyGObject? I can't seem to get it to run at all in Mac OS X. I'm trying to use papyon, which fails amazingly well if GObject isn't around.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

By [its description](http://telepathy.freedesktop.org/wiki/Papyon), it is used for async I/O only. You can try to rework the library to use any of the other Python async libraries, like asyncore, Twisted, or any other.

Also, getting PyGObject on Mac OS X is hard, but you can try to use the one from macports,  macports being the new name for darwinports

Answer (score 0):

You can instally PyGobject on Mac OS X with Darwinports, instructions [here](http://py-gobject.darwinports.com/) .

Comment: I don't like Darwinports/macports it eats my disk space p like there's no tomorrow